# Xcode: Unable to boot the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

I am developing an app with ReactNative and I am using Xcode to simulate. Recently I cannot start the simulator, and the terminal gives me following error message:

Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/Frameworks/InstrumentsPackaging.framework/Versions/A/Resources/XRPackageModel.momd/XRPackageModel 9.0.omo'

Also the Xcode simulator says: "Unable to boot the simulator".

I have restarted the computer, installed node, xcode and all necessary components but it does not work.. I have Xcode version 9.2 and node v.8.11.0. Does anyone know how to fix this problem??

Comment: It seems this question is not related with React-Native. Did you check command line tools from `Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools` ? It should be select Xcode version that installed in your Application folder.

Comment: Yes, I have done that, but seems like that is not the problem..

Comment: What is the output when you write this command `xcrun simctl list devices` to your terminal? You should see all available devices.